# Next.js Calculator App: Keyboard input resets number state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I am building a simple calculator app using Next.js. Everything works as supposed when user uses HTML buttons, but I also wanted him to be able to use his keyboard, so I set an event listener, however for some reason when user uses the specified buttons, the number state resets to 0 and then changes to a specified digit (even though the digit should be concatenated to the existing number).

Here is the code:

```
'use client'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {const [number, setNumber] = useState('0');
    const [number2, setNumber2] = useState('');
    const [lastOperator, setLastOperator] = useState(null);
    const [clear, setClear] = useState('AC');
    const [isOperational, setIsOperational] = useState(false);
    const numberRef = useRef();
    const number2Ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts.
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        };
    }, [])

    function handleKeyPress(event) {
        console.log('number: ' + number)
        const keyMap = {
            '1': () => appendNumber('1'),
            '2': () => appendNumber('2'),
            '3': () => appendNumber('3'),
            '4': () => appendNumber('4'),
            '5': () => appendNumber('5'),
            '6': () => appendNumber('6'),
            '7': () => appendNumber('7'),
            '8': () => appendNumber('8'),
            '9': () => appendNumber('9'),
            '0': () => appendNumber('0'),
            'Enter': () => pressEquals(),
        };

        const key = event.key;

        if (key in keyMap) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default browser behavior for the key.
            keyMap[key]();
        }
    }

    function adjustFontSize() {
        const numberElement = numberRef.current;
        const numberWidth = numberElement.scrollWidth;
        const containerWidth = numberElement.parentElement.scrollWidth;

        if (numberWidth > (containerWidth) - containerWidth * 0.08) {
            const newFontSize = (containerWidth * 0.92 / numberWidth) * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(numberElement).fontSize);

            numberElement.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;

            if (isOperational) {
                number2Ref.current.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
            }
        } else {
            numberElement.style.fontSize = '5rem';

            if (isOperational) {
                number2Ref.current.style.fontSize = '3rem';
            }
        }
    }

    function appendNumber(digit) {
        if (number !== '0') {
            if (isOperational) {
                setNumber2(number);
                setNumber(digit);
            } else {
                setNumber(number + digit);
            }
        } else {
            setNumber(digit);
            setClear('C');
        }

        adjustFontSize(numberRef);

        if (isOperational) {
            setIsOperational(false);
        }
    }

    function pressC() {
        setNumber('0');
        setNumber2('0');
        setIsOperational(false);
        setLastOperator(null);
        setClear('AC');

        adjustFontSize();
    }

    function pressNeg() {
        if (number.startsWith('-')) {
            setNumber(number.slice(1));
        } else if (number !== '0') {
            setNumber('-' + number);
        }

        adjustFontSize();
    }

    function pressPoint() {
        if (!number.includes('.')) {
            setNumber(number + '.');
        }

        adjustFontSize();
    }

    function pressOperator(operator) {
        setLastOperator(operator);

        if (number2 !== '0') {
            pressEquals();
            setIsOperational(true);
        } else {
            setNumber2(number);
            setNumber('0');
        }

    }

    function pressBackspace() {
        setNumber(number.slice(0, number.length - 1))

        adjustFontSize();
    }

    function pressEquals() {
        const isFloatingPoint = number.includes('.') || number2.includes('.');
        const num1 = isFloatingPoint ? parseFloat(number) : parseInt(number);
        const num2 = isFloatingPoint ? parseFloat(number2) : parseInt(number2);

        switch (lastOperator) {
            case '+':
                setNumber((num2 + num1).toString());
                break;
            case '-':
                setNumber((num2 - num1).toString());
                break;
            case '*':
                setNumber((num2 * num1).toString());
                break;
            case '/':
                setNumber((num2 / num1).toString());
                break;
            case '^':
                setNumber(Math.pow(num2, num1).toString());
                break;
        }
        setNumber2('0');
    }


    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <div id={styles.calculator}>
                <div id={styles.display}>
                    <div id={styles.number2Div}>
                        <p id={styles.number2} ref={number2Ref}>{number2}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id={styles.numberDiv}>
                        <p id={styles.number} ref={numberRef}>{number}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id={styles.buttons}>
                    <button onClick={pressC} className={styles.button}>{clear}</button>
                    <button onClick={pressNeg} className={styles.button}>neg</button>
                    <button onClick={() => pressOperator('^')} className={styles.button}>^</button>
                    <button onClick={() => pressOperator('/')} className={styles.button}>/</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('1')} className={styles.button}>1</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('2')} className={styles.button}>2</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('3')} className={styles.button}>3</button>
                    <button onClick={() => pressOperator('*')} className={styles.button}>*</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('4')} className={styles.button}>4</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('5')} className={styles.button}>5</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('6')} className={styles.button}>6</button>
                    <button onClick={() => pressOperator('-')} className={styles.button}>-</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('7')} className={styles.button}>7</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('8')} className={styles.button}>8</button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('9')} className={styles.button}>9</button>
                    <button onClick={() => pressOperator('+')} className={styles.button}>+</button>
                    <button onClick={pressBackspace} className={styles.button}><Image width={64} height={64}
                                                                                      src="/backspace.png" alt="Back"/>
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => appendNumber('0')} className={styles.button}>0</button>
                    <button onClick={pressPoint} className={styles.button}>.</button>
                    <button onClick={pressEquals} className={styles.button}>=</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

I really can't find the reason, because other states stay untouched. I tried to look into the appendNumber function that is called when user presses buttons, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it, since it works fine when the user calls it by pressing HTML buttons. And also I set some logging and discovered that the number is already 0 even before reaching that function, so that put me in even more confusion

I also tried to enable React's strict mode, but that changed nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleKeyPress`, as an event handler, has a stale closure over the `number` and other states it references.

Update the code a bit to store `handleKeyPress` (*declared each render cycle*) in a React ref that is referenced by a ***stable*** callback reference used as the event listener. This is so the *current* "version" of `handleKeyPress` with the *current* closure over the state is accessed.

Example:

```js
const handleKeyPressRef = useRef(handleKeyPress);
handleKeyPressRef.current = handleKeyPress;

useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => handleKeyPressRef.current(e);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);

  // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts.
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
  };
}, []);
```

You'll want to also round out the rest of the keys that can be pressed to use the calculator. For example:

```js
function handleKeyPress(event) {
  const keyMap = {
    "1": appendNumber.bind(null, "1"),
    "2": appendNumber.bind(null, "2"),
    "3": appendNumber.bind(null, "3"),
    "4": appendNumber.bind(null, "4"),
    "5": appendNumber.bind(null, "5"),
    "6": appendNumber.bind(null, "6"),
    "7": appendNumber.bind(null, "7"),
    "8": appendNumber.bind(null, "8"),
    "9": appendNumber.bind(null, "9"),
    "0": appendNumber.bind(null, "0"),
    "/": pressOperator.bind(null, "/"),
    "*": pressOperator.bind(null, "*"),
    "-": pressOperator.bind(null, "-"),
    "+": pressOperator.bind(null, "+"),
    "^": pressOperator.bind(null, "^"),
    ".": pressPoint,
    Enter: pressEquals,
    Backspace: pressBackspace
  };

  const key = event.key;

  if (key in keyMap) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default browser behavior for the key.
    keyMap[key]();
  }
}
```

[image: Edit next-js-calculator-app-keyboard-input-resets-number-state]